# Application of Mean Value Theorem: $f'(b) = \lim_{x\downarrow b} f'(x) = \lim_{x\uparrow b} f'(x) =: \gamma $

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a<b<c$. Furthermore let $f: [a,c] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous let $f_{|(a,b)}$ and $f_{|(b,c)}$ be differentiable with $$\lim_{x\downarrow b} f'(x) = \lim_{x\uparrow b} f'(x) =: \gamma $$ Show that $f$ is differentiable in $b$ with $f'(b) = \gamma$.

Today I just had my first lecture on differentiation and my professor suggested to prove this in order to get familiar with the Mean Value Theorem. However I have no idea whatsoever how to apply the Mean Value Theorem. The statement itself also has a strong resemblance sequential criterion for continuity, but that does not help me either.

I'd really appreciate tips, or at least a start for the proof, I can work with.

Comment: did you learn that $f'(x_0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$ in $\varepsilon\!-\!\delta$ terms??

Comment: Can I just use the definition of the derivatives like that, let $x \to b$ from above and below and since both limits are equal the limit is also $f'(b)$?

We have not used $\epsilon - \delta$ terms, but you are probably referring to the differential quotient. (?)

Comment: Yes,... on the limit $f'(b)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(b+h)-f(b)}{h}$, think about how $b+h$ moves toward $b$.

Comment: The advice to use the Mean Value Theorem is 100% correct. What do you know about $\dfrac{f(b+h)-f(b)}{h}$ for $h>0$, and, then, for $h<0$?

Comment: @TedShifrin For $h>0$ and $h<0$ the function is differentiable with $f'(x)$. Also if I let $h \to b$ from above and below both limits are equal. The mean value theorem says that under certain conditions (which are fulfilled here) that there exists an $x_0$ such that $f'(x_0) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$. All I understood from the MVT is that, between two points of a continuous function, there exists a tangent to another point between those two which is parallel to the line from point one to point two. I have no idea though how to apply that knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strategy is that we just need to prove $f$ has left and right derivatives at $b$. We provide the proof of right derivative.

> By **Mean Value Theorem**, we have
>
> > For any $x\in(b,c)$, there exist $\beta\in(b,x)$, which satisfies
> >
> > > $\frac{f(x)-f(b)}{x-b}=f'(\beta)$
>
> Then we let $x\rightarrow{b^+}$, which means $\beta\rightarrow{b^+}$, so that we have
>
> > $lim_{x\rightarrow{b^+}}\frac{f(x)-f(b)}{x-b}=lim_{x\rightarrow{b^+}}f'(\beta)=\gamma$

Same is the left derivative.

Comment: $x_0$ is just a point $\in (b,c)$?

Comment: $x_0$ is $b$. I'm wrong.